# Am I using "sep = 'x'" wrong in to_csv with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters, csv

I have a program that reads in a spreadsheet and manipulate some things, then save out a config file so you can get back to the same kind of formatting you set up at a future time. The config file is being saved as a csv.

I am running into an issue where a column in one dataset has commas in it, which breaks things. So I used the 'sep' paramter of to_csv and read_csv to avoid the issue, but it still happens.

This is the column name that is causing the problem:
['Choices, Calculations, OR Slider Labels']

I used 'sep = '|' to read and write the csv file, but the issue remains.

Thanks!

Here is the code...

```
def fxThree_A(self):
    # function to save column choices to file
    # get name for configuration from user
    #
    # save values from list of active columns to .csv file
    self.config_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['config_name','active_columns', 'inactive_columns']) 
    self.config_df.loc[0,'config_name'] = 'config_one'
    self.config_df.loc[0,'active_columns'] = ','.join(self.columns_active)
    self.config_df.loc[0,'inactive_columns'] = ','.join(self.columns_inactive)
    self.config_df.to_csv(self.rootFolder + '__config.csv', sep = '|', index=False)
    print(self.columns_inactive)

def fxThree_B(self):
    # function to read column choices from file
    # read in the config file
    self.config_df = pd.read_csv(self.rootFolder + '__config.csv', sep = '|',)#, encoding='ISO-8859-1')
    # display list of preset configurations
    # pick which config to use from dropwdown
    # apply stored settings to current columns
    self.columns_active = self.config_df.loc[0,'active_columns'].split(",")
    self.columns_inactive = self.config_df.loc[0,'inactive_columns'].split(",")
    # change button colors to match the new values
    for button in self.column_buttons:
        if button.cget("text") in self.columns_active:
            button.configure(bg = "light green")
        elif button.cget("text") in self.columns_inactive:
            button.configure(bg = "red")    
        # catch any buttons not in the list for some reason, i.e. if the file format changed since last time the config was saved
        else:
            button.configure(bg = "orange")
            tk.messagebox.showerror("Alert", "File format changed since configuration was last saved. Please re-select columns and re-save your configuration.")
```

Answer (score 0):

OH MAN.

It wasn't the separator in the file, it was how I was joining the list together into a string, in order to write out the list as one cell of the table.

I changed the ',' in this line to '||', and that solved the problem.

```
self.config_df.loc[0,'inactive_columns'] = '||'.join(self.columns_inactive)
```

Sometimes posting the issue creates a moment of clarity :)

Should I leave this up for others?